# Chown in Dockerfile works sporadically

Tags: docker, docker-compose, chown

I already read the discussions about chown and volumes in dockerfile but I could not solve my problem.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM  ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /tests/
RUN mkdir /tests/logs
RUN mkdir /tests/folder_to_watch

# add user
RUN groupadd myuser \
    && adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home --uid 1000 --ingroup myuser myuser \
    && chown -R myuser:myuser /tests/logs/ \
    && chown -R myuser:myuser /tests/folder_to_watch/

USER myuser
```

In my docker-compose.yml then I mount the volumes as follow:

```
volumes:
        - /mypath/logs/:/tests/logs/
        - /maypath/folder_to_watch/:/tests/folder_to_watch
```

Inside the container I observe the following situation:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       4096 Oct 27 16:45 logs
drwxrwxr-x 2 1000 myuser 4096 Oct 27 16:00 folder_to_watch
```

I can't understand how come the chown is working for one directory but not for another.

Comment: Did you set the correct ownership in your filesystem too?

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. I am definitely an idiot.